# Why transition not start if page is not active

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions

Why my transition start only if page in browser is active and how i can avoid it.
That is my code:

```
object.attr("style", "transition: 10s ease; transform: translateX('3000px');");
```

Comment: Probably because the brower doesn't want your page to hog CPU power if it's not active anyway.

Comment: How can I bypass this restriction on my page actions should occur synchronously

Comment: It's a browser based restriction. Instead of using CSS you would have to use a JS timer.

Comment: The problem is that on many sites where there is a similar thing, there is no such problem

Comment: The main problem is that the animation just doesn't start but if I open the page and hide it it is not any no problem it's weird